# how to config mongodb behind traefik in docker-compose.yml in docker swarm mode?

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

```yaml
services:
    db:
        image: mongo:4.4-bionic
        logging: *logging
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=username
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
        command: mongod --replSet "rs0" --bind_ip_all --port 27017
        deploy:
            labels:
                - traefik.tcp.routers.db-1.entrypoints=https
                - traefik.tcp.routers.db-1.rule=HostSNI(`example.com`)
                - traefik.tcp.routers.db-1.tls=true
                - traefik.tcp.routers.db-1.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
                - traefik.tcp.routers.db-1.tls.domains[0].main=example.com
                - traefik.tcp.services.db-1.loadbalancer.server.port=27017
        volumes:
            - db:/data
        networks:
            - main
```

The above is part of my whole config. I can't access the db through

```sh
mongo -u username -p password --host example.com --port 443
```

I have no idea what's wrong... It suspend on

```
connecting to: mongodb://example.com:443/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
```

Answer (score 1):

At a high level what you need from Traefik

1. create an entry point TCP port 27017 `--entrypoints.mongo.address=:27017`
2. export your port `27017` so that your client can connect to Traefik
3. tell your Mongo container that is a TCP service with a router and enable it.
4. check your Traefik dashboard for new TCP services

Try this after you expose port `27017` on your traefik container and add an entry point `--entrypoints.mongo.address=:27017'

```
db:
    image: mongo:4.4-bionic
    logging: *logging
    environment:
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=username
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    command: mongod --replSet "rs0" --bind_ip_all --port 27017
    deploy:
        labels:
            - traefik.enable=true
            - traefik.tcp.routers.db-1.entrypoints=mongo
            - traefik.tcp.routers.db-1.service=mongo
            - traefik.tcp.routers.db-1.rule=HostSNI(`example.com`)
            - traefik.tcp.routers.db-1.tls=true
            - traefik.tcp.routers.db-1.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
            - traefik.tcp.routers.db-1.tls.domains[0].main=example.com
            - traefik.tcp.services.db-1.loadbalancer.server.port=27017
    volumes:
        - db:/data
    networks:
        - main
```

PS. you might want to change the port and think about how to limit external access to your db.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, except that last line of labels should be different.
The name of the service we are setting the loadbalancer property should be the same as the service specified before (third label line). So they should be
`traefik.tcp.routers.db-1.service=<MONGO_SERVICE_NAME>` and `traefik.tcp.services.<MONGO_SERVICE_NAME>.loadbalancer.server.port=27017`